# Display alert message if position of div is less than 300

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display alert message if position of row_3 div is less than 300, 
But am unable to solve.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function (){
    var aa = $(".row_3").position();
    var bb = aa.top;
    if (bb <= 300) {
        alert("welcome");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: everything is working fine . see here > https://jsfiddle.net/mrtbvhvc/ . what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]  - we cannot guess how roe_3 looks like and if it is in a container and the CSS of that container

Comment: Thank you, If the row_3 div is somewhere in the middle, it is not working.

Comment: like..
<div class="row_1">
<!-- height: 200px; -->
</div>
<div class="row_2">
<!-- height: 200px; -->
</div>
<div class="row_3">

</div>

Comment: It's just because offset from top of `<div class="row_3">` is greater than 300. Use `else` for alert popup in both conditions.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
if($('.row_3').offset().top<300){
    alert("alert message");
}
});
```

Work for me check here https://jsfiddle.net/ankit7290/gdznsd0c/ .

Comment: edited!
work for me. Check the fiddle [ https://jsfiddle.net/ankit7290/gdznsd0c/ ]